# $f$ weakly modular. How to prove that the order of vanishing $v_p(f)$ is well defined for $p\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \setminus H$

Tags: modular-forms

I'm studying the proof of Lemma 1.6.6 in this [Lecture notes](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masmat/files/teaching/fall15/modforms.pdf) page 16

> > **Lemma** If $f$  is weakly modular of weight $k,$ the order of vanishing $
> > v_p(f)$ is well defined for $p\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) \setminus
> >  H.$

I have difficulty to understand the proof, can someone explain to me how to prove this ?

Thanks !

Comment: There is no lemma 1.6.6, only theorem 1.6.6. Exactly what line dont you understand? Is it the line right before theorem 1.6.6 about lim (z- \gamma p) etc? For that I suggest on the left hand side replacing z by a different varaible w , and and then replace w by \gamma z since  then w \to \gamma p means z \to p

Comment: @user90219; Thanks for your comment, yes exactly. I don't understand how I prove  $$\lim_{z\to\gamma p} (z-\gamma p)^{-n}f(z)=j(\gamma,p)^{k+2n}\lim_{z\to p}(z-p)^{-n}f(z)$$  and how I can conclude from this, that $v_{\gamma p}(f)=v_{p}(f)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to replace $z$ by $\gamma z$ on the left side of the original question, so that i can replace the limit $z \to \gamma p$ by $z \to p$. So it becomes 
$\lim_{z\to p}(\gamma z- \gamma p)^{-n}f(\gamma z)=\lim_{z\to p}(\gamma z- \gamma p)^{-n}j(\gamma, p)^kf(z)$

If $\gamma z= \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, then doing the algebra (making common denominator etc) shows
$\gamma z -\gamma p =\frac{(z-p)(ad-bc)}{(cz+d)(cp+d)}=\frac{(z-p)}{(cz+d)(cp+d)}$
since $ad-bc=1$

Hence the limit becomes 
$$\lim_{z \to p}\frac{(z-p)^{-n}}{(cz+d)^{-n}(cp+d)^{-n}}j(\gamma, p)^kf(z)$$
$$=\lim_{z \to p}(cz+d)^n(cp+d)^nj(\gamma, p)^k(z-p)^{-n}f(z)$$

$$=\lim_{z \to p}(cz+d)^n(cp+d)^nj(\gamma, p)^k(z-p)^{-n}f(z)$$
$$=\lim_{z \to p}j(\gamma, p)^{2n+k}(z-p)^{-n}f(z)$$
because when $z \to p$, $cz+d \to cp+d =j(\gamma, p)$.

Then all this implies the order at $\gamma p$ and order at $p$ are the same because (by definition of order) the order is the largest number $n$ such that each side (of the line in the original question) is non-zero; we've shown the sides are equal for every $n$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help